# Can we apply different tile template to one Live tile on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

For example, I create a second tile, its initial tile template is flip; then I call ShellTile.Update(ShellTileData data) to update the tile with iconic template, what I can see is that, something was updated, and something was not. So can we apply different tile template to one Live tile on windows phone 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It's not possible to change the type of a tile when you update it.

Updating is solely intended for updating the content of the tile, not changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Every tile type in windows phone have their own characteristics, very few property's can be updated commonly,like background image.

Up to my knowledge, we can't apply one type of template to another type of tile, if you know any idea to do so, please share to all.

here the brief explanation about

[tile in windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)